# More advanced PL/SQL query result comparison

Tags: oracle, plsql

**Wider story**

I'm building an automatic grader of my students' queries. I'll start and stop Docker containers for each student and already know how to build the system around it. I'll send the query directly to the database container, together with my own correct query.

**Question**

I'd like to have 2 things when comparing two queries:

- checkbox which switches "Order of columns important, yes/no"
- checkbox which switches "Order of rows important, yes/no"

This is what I have for that "core" part.

```
sqlplus -s system/oracle@localhost:1521/xe <<EOF
    set feedback off trimspool on;
    spool result.txt;
    
    (select * from cities) MINUS (select id, name from cities);

    spool off;
    exit;
EOF
```

I need some suggestions. How would you compare two queries when the order of columns is not important? What about order of rows, do I need to force ORDER BY in every task? What is the best approach to give more automatic feedback, just printing compiler errors?

I'll appreciate every tip.

P.S. I already did my fair share of googling but without much luck for **pl/sql**.

Comment: Huh?  Do not understand.  you are referencing the table table in the MINUS operation.

Comment: Left of the MINUS is the example of my student's code and the right part of MINUS is mine (the correct one). In this example, if we both have the same resultset, file result.txt will be empty. Otherwise, our results differ.

Comment: you are going to have to use the same columns, otherwise how will MINUS know if a row is similar.  I don't think row ordering is needed.

Comment: The MINUS operator requires the same amount of columns of the same type in the same order otherwise it won't work. You'll have to build the statement dynamically with regexp and use execute immediate if you're trying to do it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DBMS_SQL` package to create cursor and get column names. What about row order my first assumption was to use `ROWNUM` pseudocolumn and after addition of it use `MINUS`. But the problem is that the only way to guarantee the ordering is to use `ORDER BY`, and I cannot generate correct `ORDER BY` part in outer select after columns were swapped. Place that column after `SELECT` with substringing is bad because it is hard to manage `UNION` then. You can ask to place some dummy column at the topmost `SELECT` which you then can replace with `ROWNUM as rn` and then go forth. Or execute both cursors and try to compare them row by row.

The code I get is below. [Here you can try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2d39139cf04e49de92f114e943da8085).

```
declare
  v_sql_t varchar(32000) := 'select 1 as a, ''q'' as b from dual union all select 2, ''a'' from dual order by 1';
  v_sql_s varchar(32000) := 'select 1 as a, ''q'' as b from dual union all select 2, ''a'' from dual order by 2';
  v_cursor integer;
  v_col_count integer;
  v_cols_t dbms_sql.desc_tab;
  v_cols_s dbms_sql.desc_tab;
  
  v_cols_select varchar2(32000);
  v_select_keyword_begin integer;
  v_final_select varchar2(32000);
  
  v_col_order integer := 1;
  v_row_order integer := 1;
begin
  v_cursor := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
  dbms_sql.parse(v_cursor, v_sql_t, dbms_sql.native);
  dbms_sql.describe_columns(v_cursor, v_col_count, v_cols_t);
  dbms_sql.parse(v_cursor, v_sql_s, dbms_sql.native);
  dbms_sql.describe_columns(v_cursor, v_col_count, v_cols_s);
  
  --Check column order
  for i in 1..v_cols_t.count loop
    if v_col_order > 0 and v_cols_t(i).col_name != v_cols_s(i).col_name then
      dbms_output.put_line('Wrong column order. Should be: ' || v_cols_t(i).col_name || ', got ' || v_cols_s(i).col_name);
    end if;
    
    if i = 1 then
      v_cols_select := v_cols_t(i).col_name;
    else
      v_cols_select := v_cols_select || ',' || v_cols_t(i).col_name;
    end if;
    
  end loop;
  
  if v_row_order > 0 then
    v_cols_select := v_cols_select || ', rownum as rn';
  end if;
  
  v_final_select := 'with t as ( select ' || v_cols_select || ' from (' || v_sql_t || ' ) )' || chr(10)
    || ', s as ( select ' || v_cols_select || ' from (' || v_sql_s || ' ) )' || chr(10)
    || ', t_s as (select * from t minus select * from s)' || chr(10)
    || ', s_t as (select * from s minus select * from t)' || chr(10)
    || 'select ''T'' as src, t_s.* from t_s
    union all
    select ''S'' as src, s_t.* from s_t';
  
  dbms_output.put_line(v_final_select);
end;
/
```